# Comparing Parent-child combination from 2 different tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have table `MAT_ITEM` and data as follows

```
+--------+-------+
| MAT_NO | CHILD |
+--------+-------+
| 9856   | 874   |
| 9856   | 856   |
| 9856   | 548   |
| 9883   | 596   |
| 9883   | 356   |
| 7845   | 101   |
| 7845   | 908   |
| 7845   | 206   |
+--------+-------+
```

Another table `MAT_REL` and data as follows:

```
+--------+----------+----------+
| MAT_NO | PARENT   | CHILD    |
+--------+----------+----------+
| 9856   |          | STEEL    |
| 9856   | STEEL    | 874      |
| 9856   | STEEL    | 856      |
| 9856   | STEEL    | 548      |
| 9856   | A-STEEL  | 874      |
| 9856   | B_STEEL  | 856      |
| 7845   |          | METAL    |
| 7845   | O_METAL  | 102      |
| 7845   | I_METAL  | 908      |
| 7845   | METAL    | 102      |
| 7845   | METAL    | 908      |
| 7845   | METAL    | 206      |
| 7845   | METAL    | 769      |
| 9883   |          | CARBON   |
| 9883   | B_CARBON | 596      |
| 9883   | C_CARBON | 356      |
| 9883   | CARBON   | 596      |
| 9883   | CARBON   | 147      |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

Basically the row with empty `PARENT` in `MAT_REL` is considered as the TOP Parent and it's child will be considered as `PARENT` for my comparison in `MAT_REL`. `MAT_REL` may contain Parent as other values as well (*eg., A_STEEL,B_CARBON etc.,*) which I'm not worried about. 
Something like this in `MAT_REL` is what I'm considering for comparison.

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| MAT_NO | PARENT | CHILD |
+--------+--------+-------+
| 9856   | STEEL  | 874   |
| 9856   | STEEL  | 856   |
| 9856   | STEEL  | 548   |
| 9883   | CARBON | 596   |
| 9883   | CARBON | 147   |
| 7845   | METAL  | 102   |
| 7845   | METAL  | 908   |
| 7845   | METAL  | 206   |
| 7845   | METAL  | 769   |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

Now I want to compare `MAT_ITEM` and `MAT_REL` whether the `MAT_NO & CHILD` in `MAT_ITEM` combo is same as `MAT_NO`,`PARENT` & `CHILD` in `MAT_REL`.I'm trying to get the non-matching rows. We cannot directly compare `MAT_ITEM` and `MAT_REL`.Direct comparison will not work because if you see for MAT_NO 9883 , direct comparison might give the result as rows are same but we have to check for CARBON and not others(B_CARBON) as overall

Expected output : (with or without child)

```
9883
7845
```

I am able to get the detail for single MAT_NO.

```
SELECT * FROM MAT_ITEM WHERE MAT_NO='7845' 

SELECT * FROM MAT_REL 
WHERE MAT_NO = '7845' AND PARENT IS NULL -- METAL (using this below)

SELECT * FROM MAT_REL 
WHERE MAT_NO = '7845' AND PARENT = 'METAL' 


SELECT DISTINCT CHILD FROM MAT_ITEM WHERE MAT_NO = '7845' 
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT CHILD FROM MAT_REL 
WHERE MAT_NO = '7845' AND PARENT = 'METAL' -- will return some rows --101
```

but not sure how to do for whole set of combinations.

Comment: Do you want all the rows in `MAT_REL` (`MAT_NO`, `CHILD`) that doesn't have an identical row in `MAT_ITEM` (`MAT_NO`, `CHILD`)? I'm confused with `PARENT` part of the sentence "combo is same as `MAT_NO`,`PARENT` & `CHILD` in `MAT_REL`"

Comment: @Scratte, we should first get the parent and then check it's corresponding child. Direct comparsion will not work. Updated my sample data. If you see for `MAT_NO` 9883 , direct comparsion might give the result as rows are same but we have to check for `CARBON` and not others(*B_CARBON*) as overall

Comment: This is my understanding: You want to start out finding a row with an empty parent (9883, NULL, CARBON), and from there the ONLY row that has a discrepancy in MAT_ITEM is (9883, 356) because there's no row in MAT_REL with (9883, CARBON, 356). This is the only interesting result row for 9883? What if there was a row in MAT_REL with (9883, 356, XXX)? Also you're not interested in finding rows in MAT_REL that doesn't exist in MAT_ITEM, like (9883, CARBON, 147)?

Comment: @Scratte, I'm looking to find out both `(9883, CARBON, 356)` and `(9883, CARBON, 147)`. if there was a row in `MAT_REL ` with (9883, 356, XXX), ignore it. I don't want that

Comment: I tried this in a SQLite database. Would you want an answer that works on a different database than SQLServer?

Comment: @Scratte , I want it in SQL Server only. Anyway provide the link of what you have tried. I will try to implement that in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Answer as per comments on the question. I tried it out on a SQLite database, and since the syntax may be off compared to SQLServer, I can only give you directions. I do not have a link to a database.

Finding the basics:

1. Find the mat_no, child pair in mat_rel where parent IS NULL
2. Find all rows in mat_rel that matches the mat_no and where parent matches the child from 1. Add the SQL from 1. in a JOIN like (SELECT ..).

Finding mismatch (comparing child=child and mat_no=mat_no):

3. Find all rows from 2, where there's no matching row in mat_item. Use a LEFT JOIN or NOT EXISTS
4. Find all rows in mat_item where there's no matching row in mat_rel from 2. Use a RIGHT JOIN or NOT EXISTS.

Finding both 3 and 4:

5. Use both SQL's with UNION ALL