# Select part of the String and update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a data as follows

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| ID    | COMMENT                                      |
+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| 3118- | Replace Id.NO 3117-52-96 Was wrongly updated |
+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| 4857  | Replace Id.NO.4875-21-96-due to 2 mistake    |
+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| 5877  | replace .ID NO 5876.69.49 due mistake 101    |
+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| 1254  | Replace Id No. 1259-93-87 due to mistake 81  |
+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I want to get the values after the `No` and before some words. Something like below

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| ID    | COMMENT                                      | NEW_VALUE  |
+-------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| 3118- | Replace Id.NO 3117-52-96 Was wrongly updated | 3117-52-96 |
+-------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| 4857  | Replace Id.NO.4875-21-96-due to mistake      | 4875-21-96 |
+-------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| 5877  | replace .ID NO 5876.69.49 due mistake        | 5876.69.49 |
+-------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| 1254  | Replace Id No. 1259-93-87 due to mistake     | 1259-93-87 |
+-------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Then I have to update the `ID` column with `NEW_VALUE`. Once  I get the `NEW_VALUE`, it will be easy to update.

What I have tried.

```
SELECT ID,COMMENT,
REPLACE(REPLACE(COMMENT,'Replace Id.NO',''),'Replace Id.NO.','')FROM MYTABLE
```

Like above i'm using multiple(*around 10*) `REPLACE` to get my required value. I'm sure there should be some easy way.

Comment: What if the comment has two "No."s?

Comment: @GordonLinoff. It will have only one `No.`

Comment: What characters are permissable? I notice that both `-` and `.` are ok. What about `/` or `' '` (a single white space)? if `' '` is "ok", what would you expect to see if something like the string `'Replace ID no 123 456 789 2 orders were wrong'`? Is a "No" always 3 blocks of numbers?

Comment: @Larnu, "No" will have some separator. There will not be any empty separater. It may be 3 or max 4 blocks but with some separator.

Comment: So what separators could it be? What is a permissible seperator?

Comment: @Larnu. Only `-` and `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One suggestion:

```
SELECT V.ID,
       V.Comment,
       SUBSTRING(V.Comment,PI.I+3,CI.I) AS NewComment
FROM (VALUES(3118,'Replace Id.NO 3117-52-96 Was wrongly updated'),
            (4857,'Replace Id.NO.4875-21-96-due to 2 mistake'),
            (5877,'replace .ID NO 5876.69.49 due mistake 101'),
            (1254,'Replace Id No. 1259-93-87 due to mistake 81'))V(ID,Comment)
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%No[ .]%', V.Comment)))PI(I)
      CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%',STUFF(V.Comment,1,PI.I+3,'')))) CI(I);
```

This uses `PATINDEX` to find the Position of `'No '`/`'No.'`, and then the first position of a character that *isn't* a number of delimiter (`0-9` or a `.` or `-` character).

Note that for the string `'Replace Id.NO.4875-21-96-due to 2 mistake'` the value `'4875-21-96-'` is returned, due to the trailing delimiter on the value.

Ideally, what you need to be doing is fixing your design here, which I assume is why you are undertaking this. As a result you'll likely need to manually "mop up" any anonalies due to the poor data.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Larnu. This is neat. It is working for all except when the string is like `Replace Id No . 1265-92-87 due to mistake 81`. space after `No` and before `.`. is there any way to fix that. If not i will do that one with `REPLACE` not a problem.

Comment: Also can you please explain me `PI.I+3`. Not able to get that

Comment: I expected *some* consistency to your data, @Avinash . You could use `REPLACE` to fix the really bad data first, yes.

Comment: `+3` means add 3 to the value of `PI.I`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PATINDEX()` :

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.COMMENT, SUBSTRING(mt.comment, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', mt.comment)-1, 10)
FROM MYTABLE mt;
```

This will assumes comment have only one number & contains 10 length.

**EDIT :**

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.COMMENT, SUBSTRING(mtt.comments, 1, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', mtt.comments)-2)
FROM MYTABLE mt CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (SUBSTRING(mt.comment, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', mt.comment), LEN(mt.comment)))
     ) tt(comments)
```

Comment: Unfortunately , The `length` is not always 10. it can vary from `7-10` .In those cases i'm getting wrong output.

Comment: @Avinash. . . In that case you can use `APPLY`.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. But it is giving me the strings after the number. Something like `Was wrongly updated`

Comment: @Avinash. .  Ohh yes. Updated

Comment: Can you please help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736175/comparing-parent-child-combination-from-2-different-tables-in-sql-server) as well . I'm looking for some clue from 2 days but couldn't get. @Yogesh